# How to remove Wireshark from my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, wireshark

I installed an application called [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html), using:

`sudo apt-get install wireshark`

I searched it and launched it. Then, I tried to uninstall it using GUI. But it is not removing.

I tried using:

`sudo apt-get remove wireshark`

And the weird thing is that the application is still in the system!

Comment: What happened when you did `sudo apt-get remove wireshark`? That should work. Also, a program will keep running after the package that it belongs to is removed; you just can't restart it after you close it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following procedure should wipe wireshark from your system:
First uninstall the wireshark package and all related configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wireshark
```

Then remove all dependencies that are no longer needed:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to simply make a comment, but seems like I have to make an answer. The method is shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOJWbAyjflk

`sudo apt-get remove --autoremove wireshark wireshark-*`

`sudo rm -rf /etc/wireshark`

check if everything is removed with `whereis wireshark`

Answer (score 0):

I used the  following commands to remove wireshark because i had the similar problem

```
sudo -i

apt-get purge wireshark-* 

apt autoremove
```

Then i checked if everything is removed using

```
whereis wireshark
```

It is directory(without the packages) was still there at /etc/ so i removed it using

```
rm -rf etc/wireshark
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to reinstall the Wireshark to restore the default config I unintentionally changed. To do so after doing what 
Rithik Gandhi says, remove the config folder located in `~/.config/wireshark`.

Comment: This is not very clear: I guess you mean that you wanted to reinstall wireshark. Therefore you removed the config folder before reinstalling.  Did you also use the `sudo apt-get remove` command in this process?

Comment: Yes exactly. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I removed it by typing "sudo apt-get autoremove" in terminal, and then going to Ubuntu Software and search for wireshark and then uninstall. It worked for me.