# Wireshark crash

Tags: qt, wireshark

While starting wireshark, I am getting following error:

```
sudo wireshark

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, offscreen, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix the problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

After installing xcb, still I get the same error.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Solutions from following links didn't worked for me:

- [How to run Wireshark on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968948/how-to-run-wireshark-on-ubuntu-17-10)
- [“Failed to load platform plugin ”xcb“ ” while launching qt5 app on linux without qt installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308128/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without)

Comment: Maybe related: [“Failed to load platform plugin ”xcb“ ” while launching qt5 app on linux without qt installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308128/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without)

Comment: Could you add some details of exactly what you did and what happened? That might yield some information that points to the real problem/solution

Answer (score 1):

With the given information, I would recommend to reinstall completely wireshark as followed:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wireshark
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin wireshark
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

Select *Yes* so that non-superusers will be able to use wireshark (practice recommended by the Wireshark Wiki)

```
sudo chgrp YOUR_USER_NAME /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+eip /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

Links:

- https://jlospinoso.github.io/software/wireshark/networks/ubuntu/2015/02/11/configuring-wireshark-on-ubuntu-14.html
- [How to remove Wireshark from my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827109/how-to-remove-wireshark-from-my-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: tried your steps, but still facing the same error

Comment: sudo apt-get install **libcap2-bin** wireshark
**sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common**
thanks it`s work for me, i did all steps, bold text maybe helped