# Can't remove Wireshark

Tags: 18.04

I installed Wireshark but in the end I didn't use it and wanted to remove it.
I installed it from Software center so I tried removing it from there and it didn't work, when I hit remove it just asks for password and for brief moment "removing" appears and just throws back to buttons to remove and launch. I then tried what was suggested in this question [How to remove Wireshark from my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827109/how-to-remove-wireshark-from-my-ubuntu-16-04-lts) and bloody thing is still here.

Now when I run `sudo apt-get remove wireshark` it says it is not installed and yet I am able to open it, it is also present on list of installed software in Software center.

How do I remove it?

Comment: If installed as a snap, `snap list` will list your snaps; `snap remove <snapname>` will remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `sudo apt autoremove` as suggested in the linked answer to remove packages that are not dependent on by others?

The [`wireshark` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/wireshark) is a meta-package. It depends on wireshark-qt (or wireshark-gtk). If you remove a meta-package, it will not automatically remove dependent packages such as wireshark-qt. The latter packages include the GUI and tools such as tshark which is likely how you observed that the "Wireshark" program is not removed even though the `wireshark` package was removed.

If `sudo apt autoremove` still did not remove the Wireshark packages, try `sudo apt purge wireshark-qt wireshark-gtk`, optionally followed by another `sudo apt --purge autoremove`. The `--purge` option ensures that configuration files are removed as well.

Comment: `sudo apt purge wireshark-qt wireshark-gtk` has done the job, I still don't understand what was the issue so it refused to remove it.